# IOS options box

Tags: ios

I tried to search but couldn't find the right term for this "option box"
Any example out there for options box like [this link](http://www.google.com/imgres?hl=en&sa=X&rlz=1C1CHFA_enUS489US489&biw=997&bih=682&tbm=isch&prmd=imvnsfd&tbnid=NpobLXMpNnZp6M%3a&imgrefurl=http://support.twitter.com/articles/20169494&docid=PFLoLacM63iZCM&imgurl=https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/Ofl8I3sHVnMKZ3V0HfasXH39YJZoqYA69wwcvzM6XtNidQnIQfobUDbXQB8cS02opHsgLxIjsZmxoNVUuL72ThIRhFXLzp0UXfNPV0KgPmkqLK-FwVU&w=404&h=297&ei=HuUtUKTVHeOqywGF-oCgDg&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=595&vpy=163&dur=20&hovh=192&hovw=262&tx=216&ty=71&sig=108774509989666883697&page=1&tbnh=160&tbnw=215&start=0&ndsp=14&ved=1t:429,r:3,s:0,i:85)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called a `UIActionSheet`.

Here is a link to the class reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html

And here is a basic example of how it works:

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"title" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"delete" otherButtonTitles:@"other 1", @"other 2", nil];
[actionSheet showInView:self.view];
```

Answer (score 1):

@NSNSPostWhenIdle: is right and also you can create alertView as following as ...

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"title" message:@"message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"button",@"button1", nil];
    [alert show];
```

If you want some custom buttons, you create UIButtons and add as subview of alertView.

I think it will be helpful to you.